# In TestCafe, Is there a way to fetch the token set by USER ROLE functionality?

Tags: javascript, testing, automation, ui-automation, testcafe

**Introduction**

I'm using TestCafe and there are some redundant steps I'm using which can be easily replaced by making direct API calls to save a lot of time. Also, in my current tests, I'm using UserRole functionality of TestCafe to avoid login in every tests.

**What's the problem?**
To make API calls, I would need a token. UserRole already saves it in a cookie but I can't find a way to fetch it.

**What I did so far?**
I did debug test to look for cookies and I see there are a bunch of cookies in the browser but I can't see relevant which can be used as a token.

There is a way for me to get the cookie using this part of the code which I'm able to fetch when I don't use User Role functionality but unsuccessful in using the below with User Role functionality:

```
  const getCookie = ClientFunction((name) =&gt; {
  const nameEQ = `${name}=`;
  const ca = document.cookie.split(';');
  for (let i = 0; i &lt; ca.length; i += 1) {
    let c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0) === ' ') c = c.substring(1, c.length);
    if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) === 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length);
  }
  return null;
});
```

but I need to know the name of the cookie which I'm not aware of how TestCafe had set it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, an authentication cookie has the [httpOnly](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies) property. It means you cannot access such a cookie from the client side. TestCafe repeats the native browser behavior and restricts access to the `httpOnly` cookie from code inside of the [`ClientFunction`](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/guides/basic-guides/obtain-client-side-info.html). Also, at present, there is no public API to use `httpOnly` cookies in test code.
Note that the TestCafe team does not recommended you manually set up cookies. This may cause unstable tests.

Answer (score 0):

The cookie management API was released in TestCafe v1.19.0. This API works in a cross-browser way and allows you to conveniently assign, delete, and receive cookies on a testing page, including `httpOnly` cookies.

```js
await t.getCookies({
    httpOnly: true
});
```

Read more in the [Release notes](https://testcafe.io/403938/release-notes/framework/2022-05-26-testcafe-v1-19-0-released#cookie-management).